# How to get response code of httpPut in java

Tags: java

I am using httpPut to java and I want to get the response code after I execute the command. What it gives me which is "response body" is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK [Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, Pragma: no-cache, Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT, Content-Type: application/json, Transfer-Encoding: chunked, Server: Jetty(8.1.8.v20121106)]
```

But I only want 200! not the whole thing. Any help? 
This is my code by the way:

```
String url = "http://localhost:80/api/clients/";
    String clientID = "1234";

    httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPut putRequest = new HttpPut(url + clientID);
    putRequest.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    putRequest.setHeader("Charset", "UTF-8");

    System.out.println(putRequest);
    // Add your data
    putRequest.setEntity(new StringEntity(clientID, "UTF-8"));
    HttpResponse responseBody = httpclient.execute(putRequest);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTPResonse having a method called [`getStatusLine()`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.3.x/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html#getStatusLine())  which return [`StatusLine`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.3.x/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/StatusLine.html#getStatusCode()) Object.

And [StatusLine](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.3.x/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/StatusLine.html#getStatusCode()) have  a method `getStatusCode()`

So, all you need to write is

```
HttpResponse responseBody = httpclient.execute(putRequest);
int resultCode = responseBody.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();//200 in your case
```

Answer (score 0):

`responseBody.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()` should give you the responsecode of your request.